# In which file node rpc details stored in Insight-api

Tags: json-rpc, bitpay, insight-api

Bitpay insight api  https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api allows blockchain epxlore functionality

I cant find the files in which insight-api store the rpc details ?

Comment: What do you mean 'rpc details'?

Comment: rpc user name and password for getting the blockchain data.  as this insight-api listing the blockchain data ,i think it must be connected to some  node.

Comment: Typically nodes do not connect via RPC in order to sync blocks